# Using Facebook Open Graph Story with map attachment (GeoPoint)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to create some Open Graph Story with map attachment using iOS SDK and I'm have some issues.

First of all I'm having issues with the object creation... I had set a object that inherits from 'Place'. So here is the first question "how to setup a GeoPoint property using iOS Facebook SDK?"... After so many tries, I gave up... So I created a object that inherist from 'Object' and I created a custom property named 'location' as GeoPoint. But this solution brings me to same question "how to setup a GeoPoint property using iOS Facebook SDK?"

All I need is create a Story with a map that shows the venue location.

Here is my object:

```
id<FBOpenGraphObject> openGraphObject = (id<FBOpenGraphObject>)[FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
[openGraphObject setType:@"appnamespace:venue"];
[openGraphObject setTitle:[currentVenue name]];
[openGraphObject setObject:@"en_US" forKey:@"og:locale"];
[openGraphObject setObject:[[currentVenue locationLatitude] stringValue] forKey:@"appnamespace:location:latitude"];
[openGraphObject setObject:[[currentVenue locationLongitude] stringValue] forKey:@"appnamespace:location:longitude"];
```

But don't works.

It appears in Facebook Browser Objects, but with only the name. The other properties are nil.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties don't need to be prefixed by your appnamespace, and each ':' implies a new object or dictionary.

Try something like:

```
[openGraphObject setObject:@{@"latitude": [currentVenue locationLatitude], 
                             @"longitude": [currentVenue locationLongitude]}
                 forKey:@"location"];
```

Comment: can I apply a zoom in map attachment? I will share a location and the map is showing so far away... I want apply a zoom in at the location

Answer (score 2):

Your custom properties should be added in a dictionary named `data`.
In my Facebook app I have an object (inheriting from Object) with a property named `position` which is a geo_point.

This is the code I use to create the object:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
object.provisionedForPost = YES;
object[ @"title"] = @"Title";   // for og:title
object[ @"type"] = @"my_namespace:my_object";
object[ @"data" ] = @{ @"position": @{ @"latitude": @55, @"longitude": @12 }};
```