# Share map on Facebook post as a graph object (Map Attachment)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share to Facebook a "story" that has an action called share, and an object called "picture_location". "picture_location" has a custom GeoPoint property called "location".

What I want is to be able to show a story on the user's wall saying something like:

> *UserName* shared the location of a picture using *AppName*.

The problem is not the format of the story, but showing a map attachment.

The map attachment should also display a marker to show the coordinates passed in the "location" geo-point.

I have tried to solve this for 3 or more hours without success.

So far this is what I have:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *openGraphObject =
            [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"*namespace*:picture_location"
                                                    title:@"Some Title"
                                                    image:nil
                                                      url:nil
                                              description:nil];

openGraphObject[ @"location" ] = @{ @"latitude": self.imageLatitude, @"longitude": self.imageLongitude }; // imageLatitude and imageLongitude are NSNumbers


// Create an action
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

// Link the object to the action
[action setObject:openGraphObject forKey:@"picture_location"];


// Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
FBOpenGraphActionParams *params = [[FBOpenGraphActionParams alloc] init];
params.action = action;
params.actionType = @"*namespace*:share";

// If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
if([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithOpenGraphActionParams:params])
{
    // Show the share dialog
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                          actionType:@"*namespace*:share"
                                 previewPropertyName:@"picture_location"
                                             handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                                 if(error) {
                                                                     // There was an error
                                                                     NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
                                                                 } else {
                                                                     // Success
                                                                     NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                                                 }
                                                             }];

// If the Facebook app is NOT installed and we can't present the share dialog
} else {
     // FALLBACK GOES HERE
}
```

But the result is that the Facebook app opens up, with the correct story text and title, but with a blank image and no map.

Edit: These are similar questions whose solutions I have already tried with no avail.

1. [Using Facebook Open Graph Story with map attachment (GeoPoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383645/using-facebook-open-graph-story-with-map-attachment-geopoint)
2. [How to define a "GeoPoint" property in Facebook SDK for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376634/how-to-define-a-geopoint-property-in-facebook-sdk-for-ios)
3. [Using Facebook Open Graph Story with map attachment (GeoPoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383645/using-facebook-open-graph-story-with-map-attachment-geopoint)

Comment: Just to make sure, when you created the OG story (in your app settings in developer.facebook.com), you chose the layout to be "Map" rather than "Item", correct?

Comment: Yes, under edit attachment I set it as Map type, and selected my picture_location.location to me marked as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of solving this is by how the parameters are sent. I couldn't find any official documentation for this for iOS at least.

Facebook will automatically tag a place for you when your object has a geopoint property if:

1. The story has selected the map attachment instead of the usual one.
2. Within the map attachment options the custom geopoint property is selected in the mark/pin field.
3. You set the "previewPropertyName" to be this custom property
4. MOST IMPORTANTLY: Your custom property has to be wrapped within a "data" dictionary like this:

> openGraphObject[@"data"] = @{@"location": @{@"latitude":
>   self.imageLatitude, @"longitude": self.imageLongitude }};

Example code:

```
NSLog(@"Sharing: Facebook Location Share");

NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *openGraphObject =
[FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"*namespace*:location"
                                        title:@"Location to share"
                                        image:mapImage // This is the one that will be shown on the preview share dialogue
                                          url:@"An URL to link to"
                                  description:@"A description"];

// THIS is the key, the custom properties MUST be within a dictionary called "data"
openGraphObject[@"data"] = @{@"location": @{@"latitude": self.imageLatitude, @"longitude": self.imageLongitude }};

// Create an action
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

// Link the object to the action
[action setObject:openGraphObject forKey:@"location"];


// Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
FBOpenGraphActionParams *params = [[FBOpenGraphActionParams alloc] init];
params.action = action;
params.actionType = @"*namespace*:put";

// If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
if([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithOpenGraphActionParams:params])
{
    // Show the share dialog
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                          actionType:@"*namespace*:put"
                                 previewPropertyName:@"location"
                                             handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                 if(error) {
                                                     // There was an error
                                                     NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
                                                 } else {
                                                     // Success
                                                     NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                                 }
                                             }];

    // If the Facebook app is NOT installed and we can't present the share dialog
}
else
{
    // Could present an alert or use the Feed Dialogue instead
}
```