# Facebook: custom Open Graph needs Login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sharer

I would like to share a link on **Facebook** and make it show up on the *Timelime* as a map.

I have seen some apps like *Runtastic* are able to publish links as maps, by definining the map coordinates inside the html source of the link.

Ideally I would like to share such links using the simple **Share Dialog**, without implementing the full *Facebook Login* systems inside my Android and iOS apps.

But I found this written on the documentation:

> To publish Open Graph stories with the Share dialog, you do not need
>   to implement Facebook Login or ask for additional permissions. For
>   more information, see Share Dialog.
>
> If you create a custom sharing UI to publishing Open Graph stories,
>   you need to implement Facebook Login and request the publish_actions
>   permission from people using your app. This also means you need to
>   submit your app for review, see Login Review.

Does it mean that if you want to share custom Open Graph stories, you always need to implement *Facebook Login* on your mobile apps?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, and as i understand it, it depends whether you want to share it from inside your app or not. 
If you want to share it from inside your app, then yes, you'll need a login. 
If you are ok with just giving the link over to the facebook app, then giving permissions is al you need, and then make the final post inside facebook, as you usually are logged in aready.

How to create the Open Graph Object is described in Facebooks API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom

And also is there another answer which could help you:
[Using Facebook Open Graph Story with map attachment (GeoPoint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383645/using-facebook-open-graph-story-with-map-attachment-geopoint)

I hope this helps you

Comment: My mobile app would just provide the link, and the actual sharing would be done via the Facebook app, but I haven't understood if in this way it would be possible to share a custom Open Graph action and object with the map UI.

Comment: I edited my answer with two links which could help you.